# Web scraping com python, como imprimir a class de uma div

Tags: web-scraping

Gostaria de imprimir a class de uma div em phyton, o codigo do site e:

```
<div class="history-feed__collection">
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_spades" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">9</div></div>
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_hearts" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">K</div></div>
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_diamonds" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">Q</div></div>
     <div class="history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_clubs" style="width: 41px; margin-right: 18px; opacity: 1;">
         <div class="h-card__sign">2</div></div>


O Codigo que tenho e:

# Importando a BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Trocando URL
url = 'https://card.com/game'

# lendo a URL com a urllopen
html = urlopen(url)

# Enfim mostrando o poder da bs4
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# Imprimindo
print(bs.find('div', class_='history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_spades'))

# Apenas o texto
print(bs.find('div', class_='history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_spades').text)
```

Queria retirar a class da div, tipo "history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_spades" da div e imprimir ela

Comment: Ficou meio confuso, você quer imprimir a classe ou o texto da div?

Comment: imprimir a classe

Comment: Não é só fazer o print dela? `print('history-feed__card h-card h-card_sm h-card_spades')`